# Magento 2 custom layout add body class

Tags: magento2, layout, class

I create custom page layout. In admin area select this layout:

> Amin -> Products -> Categories -> MyCategory -> Design -> Layout

**Q**: How add css class to body tag?

My file:

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <!-- my references -->
</layout>
```

Tried, but not work:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="my-class" />
</body>
----------------------
<referenceContainer name="root" htmlClass="my-class" />
----------------------
<referenceContainer name="root">
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">my-class</argument>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Update**. PY Yick [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/181425/55946) not work too (for me):

```
<referenceContainer name="root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">my-class</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own workaround: use autogenerated class.
Magento 2 add class to <body> that based on layout name:

```
page-layout-{layout-id}
```

Example. My page-layout file name "*category-blog.xml*". Body will have class "**page-layout-category-blog**".

Comment: Where i need to add this? could you please help me?

Comment: @Mehta Prem Hi. Yoy can create "[custom page layout](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-create.html)". Filename of this layout will be in body classes.

Answer (score 13):

### Page Layout XML

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible out of the box via page layout XML, the existing implementation is done via PHP (checkout the `addDefaultBodyClasses()` function [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page.php#L273));

```
/**
 * Add default body classes for current page layout
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function addDefaultBodyClasses()
{
    $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass($this->request->getFullActionName('-'));
    $pageLayout = $this->getPageLayout();
    if ($pageLayout) {
        $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass('page-layout-' . $pageLayout);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

### Layout XML

Just in case anyone ends up on this question for standard layout XML it can be done this way:

Add the following attribute inside the `<body>` tags.

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="your-class"/>
</body>
```

If this doesn't work you may need to clear your caches?

Comment: Thank you for trying help. But i wrote that it not work. It work only for "<page "urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">"

Comment: I didn't notice it was a page layout sorry, I don't think it's possible out the box. I've updated my answer with my findings.

Comment: Yes. Same issue for me. @BenCrook do you have solution of that?

Answer (score 4):

The only solution i've found is to add a class to the root container.
This element will be displayed immediately after the body tag.

I've used this code:

```
<referenceContainer name="root" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-class">
</referenceContainer>
```

For me worked in the Layout Update XML for CMS pages and categories.

Unfortunately is the only solution iv'e found similar to the old "addBodyClass".

Comment: It wasn't what I was looking for as I wish to add the class on body tag. But that solution worked as well so +1 for you! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a Observer:

**=> Create the file :**

`app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/frontend/event.xml` with the following content:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="samgranger_storecodebodyclass" instance="Myvendor\Mymodule\Observer\AddBodyClass" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**=> Create the file :**

`app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Observer/AddBodyClass.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class AddBodyClass implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected Config $config;

    public function __construct(
        Config $config
    ){
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer){
        $name = $observer->getFullActionName();
        if($name == "amblog_index_category") {
            $this->config->addBodyClass("events-page");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is added the class in the begining , can we add at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Change `<referenceContainer name="root">` to the following code:

```
<referenceContainer name="root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">my-class</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceContainer>
```

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a plugin:

Create the file app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/frontend/di.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page">
<plugin name="myModuleResultPage" type="Myvendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Result\Page"/>
</type>

</config>
```

Create the file app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Plugin/Result/Page.php with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Page
{
private $context;
private $registry;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
$this->context = $context;
$this->registry = $registry;
}

public function beforeRenderResult(
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $subject,
ResponseInterface $response
){

$category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');

if($this->context->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view'
  && $category 
  && $category->getId() == <some_category_id>){
   $subject->getConfig()->addBodyClass('my_custom_class');
}

return [$response];
}
}
```

Replace the "some_category_id" with the category id that you want to add the custom body class in.

**Note:** In order to this solution to work, you need a working plugin "Myvendor_Mymodule", if you don't have the plugin, just do the following to create it:

Create the following file -

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/module.xml

With the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Myvendor_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

And the following file - app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/registration.php

with the following content -

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Myvendor_Mymodule',
__DIR__
);
```

Reference: https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/adding-custom-body-class-magento2/

Comment: Downvoted because this is crazy overkill, just use an <attribute> tag in layout per Ben Crook's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="body-class-aaa" />
</body>
```

Add these lines to layout xml file or Layout section of cms page/category.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you **just can't** add class to `<body>` in the page layout using only XML, but you can add it to the containers inside the `<body>`. In most cases this trick may help.

Since almost everything on the page is placed inside the `page.wrapper` container, you can change the class of this container instead of `<body>` in page layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" htmlClass="page-wrapper my-class" />

</layout>
```